# JSON output accents issue

Tags: php, mysql, ios, json, utf-8

I've been searching around for like 3 hours and I know there are a lot of questions like this one that have already been asked, but I haven't found any solution that works for me with my problem when trying to output accented characters of the result by a SELECT query on my database.

```
 $itemsList = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $itemsList[Items][] = ($row);
 }
 echo json_encode($itemsList);
```

This will output :

```
{"Items":  [

{"user_name":"misterP", 

"comment":"\u00c3\u00a9t\u00c3\u00a9",

"image_name":"403885300736874.jpg"}]}
```

But I need to output the accents, like this :

```
{"Items":  [

{"user_name":"misterP", 

"comment":"été",

"image_name":"403885300736874.jpg"}]}
```

- My database and tables have interclassement utf8_general_ci
- The datas inserted in my database are utf8_encoded
- my php script is in Unicode (UTF-8)
- I did " mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' ); " before the SELECT on my database
- If this can help someone : in y database, the word "été" is : "Ã©tÃ©"

So I really don't know what to do now, I am really stuck with the accents and i can't get it work. Thanks in advance !

Comment: you might want to give this page a read to see if you've missed anything in terms of encoding, and also try the test 2/3 down the page: http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That doesn't really matter. When the json is decoded, they become characters again.

If you use php 5.4 >=, you can pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to `json_encode`:

```
json_encode( $data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )
```

But again, the unicode escapes work just as well and make the data ascii safe.

Edit:

It looks like your data was already screwed, even before `json_encode`. You have "double encoded" it as utf-8 it seems.

> The datas inserted in my database are utf8_encoded

Are you using something like `utf8_encode`? You do not need to do anything in your code when you insert into your database. If you inserted the data in the database using `utf8_encode`, then that explains the double encoding. All you need is for the data to be utf-8 and have `mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' )` before inserting.

---

It is interesting to know that if your json has unescaped unicode, the json [cannot be executed as javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeHU/) even if you add parentheses if the json contains [`U+2028`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) or [`U+2029`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2029/index.htm).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using php 5.3.18
Is there a workaround for this version ?

Comment: @Seb83 json is not your problem at all, the problem is how you insert data into the database. See my edit

Comment: So the real solution is to correct the incorrect data in the database. Whatever code caused the data to be incorrectly entered will also need to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'm gonna try to change my way of inserting data ASAP :)

Yes I am using utf8_encode. Actually, here is what I do :

<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
include 'infodb.php';
And this just before the mysql_query
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('INSERT INTO Items (comment)VALUES("'.utf8_encode($_GET['comment']).'")

//$_GET['comment'] == été

Comment: @Seb83 what is the physical encoding of your php source files? This depends on your text editor and platform, if you are on windows it is most likely not utf-8 unless you have already configured it yourself. Do you also set the http header `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")` somewhere?

Comment: I should have detailed it : The data are sent from an iOS application, and the data are retrieved by the same iOS application. I don't display any data on html pages. That's why I don't set  the http header header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"). Should I set it even if it is for an iOS application ? (Yeah sorry, I should also have said that I'm a very beginner with php ^^)

Physical encoding is Unicode (UTF8 WITHOUT BOM). I am using TextWrangler on Mac and Notepad++ on my PC with Windows but most of my files are created on the Mac.

Comment: I have tried to set the header in my php file like this :
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
I have also set   mysql_set_charset( 'utf8' );  just before the insert, but the problem is still the same when I insert new data from my iOS app.

Comment: @Seb83 You can use any other content type other than `text/html`, as long as you append `;charset=utf-8`. For example, `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`. Anyway it looks like you are set, you can just directly insert data into db without `utf8_encode`. Because if `$_GET['comment'] == "été"` returns `true`, where the php source is physically utf-8, then the `$_GET` data was already utf-8 and you don't need to `utf8_encode`.

Comment: Thanks to you, It is getting better ! Now when I go and check the inserted data in the database, the word "été" appears clearly as "été", not as "Ã©tÃ©"" anymore. So, it looks like the inserting problem is fixed, thank you ! :)

But still can't display the data with the accents using the json_encode. I'll try some stuffs with the headers etc. I'm sure I'm very close now :)

Comment: @Seb83 like I originally said, when you decode the JSON, you will have the characters again. Undecoded json is just an intermediate format, it doesn't matter if it has `\uxxxx` because when you are going to use it, you have to parse the JSON first, and when you parse the json, the `\uxxxx` escape sequences become the real characters again.

Comment: Thank's a lot, it seems everything is working properly now ! 
Once again i've learned something new, as everyday thanks to people like you.
Thanks again for your time :)

Comment: I get this warning: 
"Warning: json_encode() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given"